# Rails 3 routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rake

I have a weird problem.
I was using rails with scaffold to create CRUD and stuff.
Then I added a function called cnt that should give me the count of table entries.
For example Albums.count for a cipher.
But this morning, the whole routing was directing to that page.
When I tried to visit xxx/elements
I was linked do /cntalbums.

Looked like a routing thing - this is my routes.rb:

```
Something::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :albums
  get "home/index"
  resources :elements
  root :to => 'home#index'
end
```

That's all.
I deleted the view of cnt, I deleted the method, which was locaten in albums_controller.
So there is no friggn spot left, where cnt is implemented.
But still it seems like every GET links to that page.
I got this one in my logs:

```
Started GET "/albums" for xxxx at Fri Oct 05 09:54:42 +0200 2012
Processing by AlbumsController#cnt as HTML
Parameters: {"cntalbums"=>"albums"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 47ms

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template albums/cnt, application/cnt with {:formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder]}. Searched in:
* "/kunden/nnax.de/webseiten/entwicklung/poezy/app/views"
):
 app/controllers/albums_controller.rb:18:in `cnt'
```

I had:

```
match ':cntalbums' => 'albums#cnt', :as => 'cnt_albums', :via => :get
```

Before; but I deleted that already.
So I don't have ANY clue, why I cannot see my albums, elements and so on.
Finally: rake routes gives me that:

```
albums GET    /albums(.:format)            albums#index
         POST   /albums(.:format)            albums#create
new_album GET    /albums/new(.:format)        albums#new
edit_album GET    /albums/:id/edit(.:format)   albums#edit
     album GET    /albums/:id(.:format)        albums#show
         PUT    /albums/:id(.:format)        albums#update
         DELETE /albums/:id(.:format)        albums#destroy
elements GET    /elements(.:format)          elements#index
         POST   /elements(.:format)          elements#create
new_element GET    /elements/new(.:format)      elements#new
 edit_element GET    /elements/:id/edit(.:format) elements#edit
   element GET    /elements/:id(.:format)      elements#show
         PUT    /elements/:id(.:format)      elements#update
         DELETE /elements/:id(.:format)      elements#destroy
    home_index GET    /home/index(.:format)        home#index
    root        /                            home#index
```

so for my understanding it is clear; I wanna go to albums or elements and it enters the function of the fitting controller.
But it ALWAYS tries to reach AlbumsController#cnt

Although that function does not even exist anymore

ANY hints ? :/

Answer (score 0):

Rails routes are first-come-first-routed, so if the CNT rule was above everything else, Rails will route that. Looking at the rule

```
match ':cntalbums' => 'albums#cnt', :as => 'cnt_albums', :via => :get
```

notice that any URL will match this. The path `/hello/world` will result in `:cntalbums => "hello/world"`.

If you've deleted the line from your routes but are still being routed by it, are you sure that you've restarted your Rails server? (maybe even try clearing your browser's cache, but that really shouldn't be the problem)

Comment: Yeah it was like my provider that restarted the server; now it is working again ... 
At first I was trying
match 'albums/cnt' => 'albums#cnt'
But that lead into my controller thinking, that cnt is an ID
He wanted to use the "show" function for any reason.
How could I solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Something::Application.routes.draw do
 resources :albums
 ...
 match ':cntalbums' => 'albums#cnt', :as => 'cnt_albums', :via => :get
 ...
 get "home/index"
 resources :elements
 root :to => 'home#index'
end
```

because rails routes are first come first serve